# How to store a string to file in android java code and call it for parsing in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, android, jquery, html

I am trying to implement a jQuery Mobile application in which I am parsing an HTML code of a page to find only content of a div using div-id (in example main-content-inner). I am doing so in JavaScript which is stored in my index.html code as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        //    var chck = document.getElementById("check");
        //     alert(chck.title);    
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'main.html',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {

                //cross platform xml object creation from w3schools
                try //Internet Explorer
                {
                    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                    xmlDoc.async = "false";
                    xmlDoc.loadXML(data);
                } catch (e) {
                    try // Firefox, Mozilla, Opera, etc.
                    {
                        parser = new DOMParser();
                        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/xml");
                    } catch (e) {
                        alert(e.message);
                        return;
                    }
                }
                //    var chck = document.getElementById("check");
                //    alert(chck.title);
                var abc = document.getElementById("content1");
                abc.innerHTML = (xmlDoc.getElementById("main-content-inner").innerHTML);
                //    alert(abc.innerHTML);
            }
        });
</script>
```

As jQuery cant call the HTML code of a remote page (Same Origin Policy), I am using java language code which I am using implementing on MainActivity.java of android and the HTML code is returned as a string (say i).

Now, I want to pass this "i" (from java) to javascript (in index.html) for parsing. What methods can I use to do that. Also I thought of storing the string in a file using FileWriter but I dont know how I can call the path of this new file in javascript (what to write in URL of JS).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is with a [Javascript interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript), like so:

```
class JavaScriptInterface {

            @JavascriptInterface
            public String getFileContents(){
                // read the file into a String and return it here. 
                return "the contents of your file";
            }

}
```

Then, to set the Javascript Interface on the webview:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "android");
```

and in the js of the page inside the webview:

```
function getFileContents(){
    var info = window.android.getFileContents();
    return info;
}
```

This, however, **is not asynchronous**.  if you want to implement this functionality in an async manner, you would instead:

- add a method in javascript called something like "populateFileContents(data)"
- call the `window.android.getFileContents()` from javascript,
- have that return nothing, only kick off (an asynctask probably) functionality that would read the file contents, then call, in the Java android code, `webview.loadUrl("javascript:populateFileContents(data);");` - which would pass the data from the file back to the javascript, where you could do with it what you like.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks #nebulae for answering.

However I solved my problem with some sort of digging around. I created a file using file writer and stored it in a folder in the internal SD card of Android (say folder name ABC file name XYZ).

I am then calling that file from my javascript using the absolute address of that file. The absolute address for the file ABC/XYZ is written in my JS as:

```
  url: 'file:///storage/sdcard0/ABC/XYZ.txt',
```

This method does the trick.